Prove that $U(40)/U_8(40) $ is cyclic but $U(40)/U_5(40)$ is not cyclic.
I was reading the chapter about Factor groups in Joseph A. Gallian's Contemporary abstract algebra and I ran into the following problem.
$$\text{Prove that }U(40)/U_8(40) \text{ is cyclic but } U(40)/U_5(40) \text{ is not cyclic}.$$
Here $U(n)=(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$ denotes the multiplicative group of units in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.  If $m|n$ then $U_m(n)$ denotes the kernel of the natural homomorphism $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*\to (\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^*$.  That is $x\in U(n)$ lies in $U_m(n)$ if and only if $x\equiv 1 \mod m$.
This problem got me puzzled as I found the opposite result to be true.
So basically, I attempted to solve it by brute force and what I found is the following
$$U(40)/U_8(40) = \{U_8(40), 3U_8(40), 7U_8(40), 13U_8(40)\}\\=\{\{1, 9, 17, 33\}, \{3, 27, 11, 19\}, \{7, 23, 39, 31\}, \{13, 37, 21, 29\}\}$$
Here, $U_8(40)$ has order $1$ and all the others have order $2$ which makes the factor group non-cyclic, opposed to what I am supposed to find. Similarly, I found that $3 U_5(40)$ has order $4$ which makes it a generator of $U(40)/U_5(40)$ and hence $U(40)/U_5(40)$ is cyclic.
I still don't have a full grasp yet on factor groups and I'm probably missing something big here. So could you please help me find what it is.

I have seen the notation $U(40)$ before, and I think I can guess what that is. But I have not seen $U_8(40)$ before. Could you define that for me?

@Arthur oh yes, sorry my bad. So $U(n)$ is the set of positive integers less than n and relatively prime to n. It forms a group under modular multiplication mod n. As for $U_m(n)$, it's the subset of $U(n)$ defined as follows  $U_m(n) = { a \in U(n) \text{ | } gcd(a,m) = 1 }$. And we can verify that it's a subgroup of $U(n)$. So here in our example, $U(40)={1, 3, 7, 9, 11, 13, 17, 19,  21, 23, 27, 29, 31, 33, 37, 39}$ and $U_8(40)={1, 9, 17, 33}$

I don't understand your $U_8(40)$. By your definition, also $\gcd(3,m)=\gcd(3,8)=1$, so $3\in U_8(40)$. But you don't have it in it. By the CRT we have $U(40)\cong U(8)\times U(5)$, and the quotient, I suppose, is $U(5)$, which is cyclic. The other quotient is $U(8)\cong C_2\times C_2$, which is not cyclic.

@DietrichBurde Yes you're right I made a terrible mistake in the definition I don't know what's gotten into me hahahaha. Here is the right definition : $U_m(n) = { a \in U(n) \text{ | } a \equiv 1 \text{ mod}(m) }$

Which edition of the book are you using?  There is many.

@Shaun I'm using the 10th edition.

If $U_m(n) = {a \in U(n) \mid a \equiv 1 \bmod{m} }$ for $m$ dividing $n$, then observe that $U_m(n)$ is the kernel of the surjection $U(n) \to U(m)$, so the quotient $U(n)/U_m(n) \cong U(m)$. Now, as both @DietrichBurde and yourself have pointed out, $U(5)$ is cyclic while $U(8)$ is not. Perhaps the book you mention made a typo?

I have put the definitions given in the comments, in the main question, to try and avoid this question being closed.  Is it possible you are using a different convention to to the textbook, so what you mean by $U_m(n)$ is what the textbook means by $U_{n/m}(n)$?
